# How to move Android animation to a certain position?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I need to animate a card, moving from its original position and land on top of another predefined imageview (Representing the stack of cards at a cardtable)

```
    public static ImageView REFERENCE_IMAGE_FOR_ANIMATION;
REFERENCE_IMAGE_FOR_ANIMATION = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardpile);

    public void deckButtonOnClick(View v) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(DECK.takeCard());
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(PARAMS);
    imageView.setTag("0");
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());

    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerLinearLayout))
            .addView(imageView);

}
```

My code for `MyOnClickListener` is the following:

```
public class MyOnClickListener{
Animation standardPosition = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -25f);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Animation standardPosition;

    Animation risedPositionAndChosen;

    if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
        standardPosition = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -25f);
        standardPosition.setDuration(400);
        standardPosition.setFillAfter(true);
        v.setTag("1");
        v.startAnimation(standardPosition);

    } else if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        risedPositionAndChosen = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,    Game.REFERENCE_IMAGE_FOR_ANIMATION.getRight()
                - v.getRight(), Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -Game.REFERENCE_IMAGE_FOR_ANIMATION.getTop());
        risedPositionAndChosen.setDuration(400);
        risedPositionAndChosen.setFillAfter(true);
        v.setTag("0");
        v.startAnimation(risedPositionAndChosen);

    } else if (v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {

    }
    ((View) v.getParent()).invalidate();
}

}
```

It is the first "else if" statement in my `OnClickListener` that I somehow need to change.

The `REFERENCE_IMAGE_FOR_ANIMATION = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardpile);` is the card I need to "land on".

My layout for the game screen contains a nested `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` inside. When the animation starts the card sort of "slips under" the layouts higher in the hierarchy. What should I do inorder for it to "float on top"?

Comment: You should replace LinearLayout with RelativeLayout and make sure that the view you want on top is the last one inserted in the RelativeLayout. I hope it helps :)

Comment: What do you mean? The image i want on top is never defined in the XML file. I create it and add it programmatically.

My layout hierarchy:

GridLayout{ScrollView{LinearLayout{"All cards here"}}, ImageView, ImageButton}

Comment: The ImageView in the comment above is where i want my card moved

Comment: I said to replace the LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout that is in your scrollview..

Comment: Thank you! the animation is still wrong though